# Converting encoded base 64 image string onto input stream without saving image into local file system

Tags: java, image, jpeg

```
#/**
 * This method is used to convert encoded base 64 image string into inputStream without saving it into file system
 * @param : encodedBase64Image - Contains encoded base 64 image string
 * @return :InputStream 
 *
 */#
```

> encoded base 64 image string into inputStream without saving it into file system

```
InputStream getInputStream(final String encodedBase64Image) {
        long mediaId
        // create a buffered image
        BufferedImage image = null
        byte[] imageByte;
        imageByte = EncodingGroovyMethods.decodeBase64(encodedBase64Image) // Coverting encoded image string into byte array
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte)
        image = ImageIO.read(bis)
        RenderedImage rImage = (RenderedImage) image; // forming rendered image
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(rImage, "jpg", os); // JPEG Image is formed in OutputStream
        InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()); /* OutputStream into Inputstream */
        return InputStream
    }
```

> encoded base 64 image string into inputStream without saving it into file system

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: `return InputStream`? I doubt this code compiles.